# NullPointerException with no stack trace

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Java, for some reason, is giving me a `NullPointerException`. I know that this is usually easy to fix, but in this case, I can't figure out why it's throwing it in the first place. Why can't I figure it out? Well, because it has no stack trace! Here's my code:

```
package redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.modifiers;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageByEntityEvent;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
import redempt.divinity.ability.AbilityType;
import redempt.divinity.ability.modifier.ProjectileModifier;

public class NoGravity extends ProjectileModifier {
    Vector vector;
    Location lastpos;
    @Override
    public void onUse(Player player, Entity projectile) {
        vector = player.getLocation().getDirection().normalize();
        lastpos = projectile.getLocation();
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "No gravity";
    }
    @Override
    public Material getRepresentation() {
        return Material.FEATHER;
    }
    @Override
    public AbilityType getType() {
        return AbilityType.PROJECTILE;
    }
    @Override
    public void onHit(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(Entity entity) {
        try {
            if (lastpos == null) {
                lastpos = entity.getLocation();
            }
            if (entity.getLocation().getBlock().getType().equals(Material.AIR)) {
                entity.setVelocity(vector);
            }
            lastpos = entity.getLocation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`onTick()` is called every tick, `onUse()` is called before it starts calling `onTick()`, and here's the console output:

```
[11:26:52 INFO]: Exception
[11:26:52 WARN]: java.lang.NullPointerException
... this repeats often
```

So what the hell does this mean, why does it happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Once you have enough exceptions thrown at the same point, it drops the stack trace.  You need to look at the start of your log. (Or you can use a debugger to breakpoint which this Exception occurs)

Comment: Regardless of if lastpos is null, you still do  `lastpos = entity.getLocation();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably issue with JVM, pass this argument to it in order to have full stack trace:

```
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Now, `NPE` is there because something out there is `null` and you try to call a method from it. Potential candidates are `entity` since you call `entity.getLocation()`, then `entity.getLocation()`, since you call `entity.getLocation().getBlock()`, or even object you get when calling `entity.getLocation().getBlock().getType()` Check them out too not only `lastpos` .

Comment: That seems to have given me the stack trace back, thanks